# $_FILES does not accept value

Tags: php

I have an input that keeps photos on itself . And I'm using it for a website panel . But when it saves the photo , in editing , I should put a value for it to read the last picture . but it doesn't work well. `$_files` is empty again ! What can I do for that ?

thanks

```
<input<?php if(!empty($target_file)) echo ' value="'.$target_file.'"';?> type="file" id="photo" name="photo" class="photo" />
```

---

```
<?php
    $photo= $_FILES['photo'];
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    srand(time());
    $random_num = (rand()%99999);
    $target_file = $target_dir . $random_num . basename($_FILES["a_photo"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
?>
```

I hace checked stackoverflow for my answer but didn't find anything .

Comment: try to check that your form have enctype = 'multipart/form-data' ornot.if not then please put it and check

Comment: did you write ` enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag

Comment: shouldn't `$_FILES["photo"]` be `$_FILES['a_photo']`?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh the form has this attribute.

Comment: @BushraShahid the form has this attribute.

Comment: then do this $_FILES["photo"] be $_FILES['a_photo']

Comment: @DavidR. I edited it for here . In my code that is p_photo and without any problem

Comment: See waht the name you give to the field in form that only name you need to put in $_FILES. if it is p_photo then it should be $_FILES['p_photo']

Comment: See what's stored in with `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: @anantkumarsingh this is correct in my php page . I edited it for here . I think the problem is for the `value=""` . because the value of the photo variable is an array and I don't know What to do for that.

Comment: @pbaldauf I got an echo from `var_dump($_FILES)` .result was: ` array(0) { } `

Comment: you cannot send an array with $_FILSE, because when you put a file-name it itself create an array of$_FILES with name, size, tmp_name etc

Comment: @anantkumarsingh so what should be the value of the `$_FILES` input ?

Comment: it will be file name only.means just a file selected by this filed.As normaly you are doing in fileupload

Comment: 1) `$_FILES` will indeed be empty, it only temporarily holds files uploaded *in the current request*. 2) You cannot  pre-fill file input fields. – See the duplicate for how to handle this.